# Core Data (public) database - Predicate not working?

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data, predicate

I'm working on a Core Data / CloudKit **public** Database.

Apple recommends not to delete the object but to set a variable e.g. isTrashed to `true`.
After that a predicate should be set for the FetchRequest so that this object is no longer displayed.

So in my view I set this variable to true when an object is deleted and this is also set correctly. Here is the query directly from the dashboard:

[image]

Unfortunately the predicate doesn't work as it should and the object is still displayed. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

`Fetch Request`

```swift
static var productsByName: NSFetchRequest<Product> {
        /// create Request
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Product> = Product.fetchRequest()
        
        /// sortDescriptor
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isTrashed = false") // <-- predicate for isTrashed
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Product.name, ascending: true)]
        
        return request
    }
```

`ContentView.swift`

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @SectionedFetchRequest(fetchRequest: ContentView.productsByName, sectionIdentifier: \Product.manufacturer?.name)
    var products: SectionedFetchResults<String?, Product>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(products) { section in
                        Section(header: Text(section.id ?? "unassigned")) {
                            ForEach(section) { product in
                                NavigationLink(destination: productDetailView(product: product)){
                                    Text(product.name ?? "na")
                                }
                            }
                            .onDelete { rows in
                                for row in rows {
                                    let product = section[row]
                                    if storageProvider.persistentContainer.canDeleteRecord(forManagedObjectWith: product.objectID) {
                                        storageProvider.deleteProduct(product)
                                    } else {
                                        product.isTrashed = true  // <-- here the value for isTrashed is set
                                        
                                        do {
                                            try storageProvider.persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
                                        } catch {
                                            storageProvider.persistentContainer.viewContext.rollback()
                                            print("Failed to save context: \(error)")
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

`edit 1`

*additional info:*

I added this code to the `detailView` of the products to check if the value is set correct:
`Text("is trashed: \(product.isTrashed ? "true" : "false")")`

... and **yes** it is:
[image]

---

`edit 2`

I also tried these for the query:

- `request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isTrashed = 0")`
- `request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isTrashed = FALSE")`
- `request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isTrashed = NO")`
- `request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isTrashed = 0")`
- `request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isTrashed == FALSE")`
- `request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isTrashed == NO")`
- `request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K =  %@", argumentArray: [#keyPath(Product.isTrashed), false])`
- `request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K ==  %@", argumentArray: [#keyPath(Product.isTrashed), false])`

So I don't think the query itself is the problem :/

---

`edit 3`

but for example this predicate directly on the view is working:

```swift
.onChange(of: testProd) { _ in
    products.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "isTrashed = true")
}
```

That's why I don't understand why the predicate on the FetchRequest isn't working.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I don't think "false" works, try "FALSE" or "NO" and perhaps also "==" instead of "="

Comment: I just tried all of these (4) variations. Sadly none of them worked. Also I got the first query from the apple-developer-video [here](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10650) ([screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/ceFFsql)) so I think the query should be okay?

Comment: *just for info:* I also deleted the app from the test device in between the tests.

Comment: `isTrashed = 0`?

Comment: just tried `isTrashed == 0` and `isTrashed = 0` - also not working :/ So I don't think the query is the problem.

Comment: this query: `products.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "isTrashed = true")` is working just fine if I add it to the view with `.onChange` (used on the FetchedResults array). But when I add the same query to the FetchRequest it doesn't work. *also added it to the post above*